# len of empty dask dataframe raises exception

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I need to known the length of dask dataframe, though if I'm reading an empty file - the code produces an exception:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ddf = dd.read_csv(r'empty_file.csv', names=['x'])
    print(len(ddf))
```

As a result I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

However code above works correctly if **file is not empty**.

Is there a better way of getting length of the dask dataframe to also handle case where file is empty?

UPDATE:

Stacktrace
[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's `len` that is generating the exception, not `read_csv`?

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Stacktrace shows that it's print line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **.empty** to verify if yor dataframe is empty. Like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ddf = dd.read_csv(r'empty_file.csv', names=['x'])
    if not ddf.empty:
        print(len(ddf))
    else:
        print("Empty dataframe")
```

Comment: @Vladislav Varslavans if this response solve your problem please mark this answer as correct. Thanks!